# While mapping the dictionary inside the Series for labeling the categorical values getting the output Series in all null

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, machine-learning, label-encoding

[image][image][image]    zipcode =[str(x) for x in zipcode]
label = list(range(len(zipcode)))

```
directory = {}
  for i in label:
  directory[zipcode[i]] = i

data['zipcode']=data['zipcode'].map(directory)

[t][1]
```

After the above code, I am getting whole columns as `Null` values instead of getting all in the numerical label

Comment: Help us help you - please provide some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it

Comment: I am adding a screenshot

Comment: Avoid adding screen shots instead provide code snippet that can be copy pasted and allows others to reproduce the issue.

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: can you add text for the dataframe instead?  You can paste the output of `data.to_string()`

Comment: Now you can see the topmost image is my actual problem

Comment: I am expecting the whichever the zipcode is available inside the zip code columns they should be converted according to my label with the help of the dictionary by using mapping but I am getting the all the values in the form of Null ...but the dictionary i am have made is similar kind of dictionary which is been used to make mapping inside the columns of dataframe

Comment: My Problem resolve my end try to ignore it

Comment: data['zipcode']=data['zipcode'].astype(str).map(directory)  did u try this?

Answer (score 0):

dtype of the zipcode I had change but I have kept the sampe dtypes of the zipcode that was previous one so from that I have got the label on the  columns